# how to select multiple items at a time in ng2

Tags: javascript, angular

In ng2, I want to select multiple items when i click on the item, as of now, it selecting one item where clicked, but, i want to retain already selected items as well when i click on the current selection.

html

```
<span class="tag" *ngFor="let selectedTagItem of tagsAvailable;let i = index" [ngClass]="{'activeTag': selectedIdx == i}" (click)="selectItem(i)">{{selectedTagItem}}</span>
```

ts

```
    export class listComponent implements OnInit {
     public tagsAvailable:string[] = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
        'California', 'Colorado']

    selectedIdx = 0;
    selectItem(index):void {
          this.selectedIdx = index;
      }
}
```

plnker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/7b3VUnGERBspSU1JKEXi?p=preview

this code, currently selecting only one item that i clicked, but, what i am expecting is i want to retain the last selection, previous so on.
Any help

Comment: Provide plunker link.

Comment: why not use an array to store your alreay selected items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do like this.

```
  selectItem(index,event):void {  
    console.log(index);  
    event.target.attributes.class.nodeValue="tag activeTag"  
    this.itemsSelected.push(this.tagsAvailable[index]);  
    this.itemsSelectedIndex.push(index)  
  }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/R7FcJa9N58hajBV6nSBn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using as below

```
<p><span class="tag"
        *ngFor="let selectedTagItem of tagsAvailable;let i = index" 
      (click)="selectItem(i)">{{selectedTagItem}}</span></p>
      {{itemsSelected |json}}


selectItem(index):void {
      this.itemsSelected.push(index);

      console.log(this.itemsSelected);
  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQRqqakyCiDW0lJS9QK9?p=preview)**